# Javascript Scroll Load Dynamic Content Into Page When User Reaches Bottom

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic

I have tried over and over to solve this but I feel like I'm missing something.

Basically I am trying to make it so my website will load additional content when the user reaches the bottom of the page.

The website: http://www.dark-quill.com/

I have used this as a template for what I'm trying to do but I have no idea what any of it means.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function yHandler(){
        // Watch video for line by line explanation of the code
        // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eziREnZPml4
        var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
        var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
        var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
        var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
        if(y >= contentHeight){
            // Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here
            wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData"></div>';
        }
      }
      window.onscroll = yHandler;
    </script>
    <style>
      div#wrap{
        width:1000px;
        margin:0px auto;
      }

div.newData{height:1000px; background:#09F; margin:10px 0px;}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status">0 | 0</div>
    <div id="wrap">

    // what goes here?? htmL?

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have NEVER used JavaScript / Ajax / Jquery before all I understand is html and css. So if someone could PLEASE explain to me very clearly of what I'm supposed to do to get this working, I would really love it.

For example: I don't understand what the "wrap" div purpose is. I also dont understand what is meant by "Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here".

Again, as you can see on my website, the stories are listed one after the other, and after about 5 stories or so, I want it so the website will load an additional 5 stories once the user reaches the bottom of the page, and continuously do that until there are no more stories. Just a very simple thing that seems to be super complex to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would Need a server action somewhere that would return you the HTML for the next 5 items.   Your Ajax call to that url would retrieve that Information and then it would be appended to you Element.

```
 $.ajax({
     url : 'url',
     type : 'GET',
     data : {
    'parameter' : 10
     },
     dataType:'json',
     success : function(data) {              
         alert('Data: '+data);
     }
 });
```

Comment: So I would put that in where it says "Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here"?

Also, how do I specify WHERE it gets the html from, and how would I make it so it gets NEW html after fetching the previous one? So that it repeats the process over and over until there is no more additional content to get. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are loading the content on the page now.  Like how are you going to load the first 5 Items?